# How to pass php variable into mysql stored procedure while calling in php

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have to pass PHP variable in to stored procedure calling,stored procedure is new for me,please help me..Thanks in advance

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
if(isset($_POST["state_id"]) && !empty($_POST["state_id"]) && isset($_POST["cat_id"]) && !empty($_POST["cat_id"])){
    $categoryid=$_POST["cat_id"];
    $qttypeid=$_POST["state_id"];
    if(($_POST["state_id"]=='1') || ($_POST["state_id"]=='2') ){
        $res4=mysqli_query($con,"call PP4($categoryid,$qttypeid)");
        echo $res4;
        while($res4a=mysqli_fetch_array($res4)){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$res4a['locId'].'">'.$res4a['access'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        $res4=mysqli_query($con,"call PP1");
        while($res4a=mysqli_fetch_array($res4)){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$res4a['locId'].'">'.$res4a['access'].'</option>';
        }   
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: how to pass php variable into parameter of stored procedure while calling it, in php

Comment: Why your code isn't working ? Do you have error ?

Answer (score 0):

Well you're open yo SQL injection, you will need to use prepared statment to sanatize your arguments. Here is how you do with prepared statment to call a stored procedure.

```
$connect = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// bind the first parameter to the session variable @categoryid
$stmt = $connect->prepare('SET @categoryid := ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $categoryid);
$stmt->execute();

// bind the second parameter to the session variable @qttypeid
$stmt = $connect->prepare('SET @qttypeid := ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $qttypeid);
$stmt->execute();

// execute the stored Procedure
$result = $connect->query('call PP4(@categoryid, @qttypeid, @msg)');

// getting the value of the OUT parameter
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT @msg as _output');
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();                       
echo $row['_output'];
```